# Extend base class properties

Tags: c#, oop

I need your help to extend my base class, here is the similar structure i have.

```
    public class ShowRoomA
    {
            public audi AudiModelA { get; set; }
            public benz benzModelA { get; set; }
    }   
    public class audi
    {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string AC { get; set; }
            public string PowerStearing { get; set; }
    }
    public class benz
    {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string AC { get; set; }
            public string AirBag { get; set; }
            public string MusicSystem { get; set; }
    }
//My Implementation class like this
    class Main()
    {
      private void UpdateDetails()
      {
        ShowRoomA ojbMahi = new ShowRoomA();
        GetDetails( ojbMahi ); // this works fine
      }
      private void GetDetails(ShowRoomA objShowRoom)
      {
         objShowRoom;
         objShowRoom.audi = new audi();
         objShowRoom.audi.Name = "AUDIMODEL94CD698";
         objShowRoom.audi.AC = "6 TON";
         objShowRoom.audi.PowerStearing = "Electric";

         objShowRoom.benz= new benz();
         objShowRoom.benz.Name = "BENZMODEL34LCX";
         objShowRoom.benz.AC = "8 TON";
         objShowRoom.benz.AirBag = "Two (1+1)";
         objShowRoom.benz.MusicSystem = "Poineer 3500W";
      } 
    }
// Till this cool.
// Now I got requirement for ShowRoomB with replacement of old audi and benz with new models and new other brand cars also added.
// I don't want to modify GetDetails() method. by reusing this method additional logic i want to apply to my new extended model.
// Here I struck in designing my new model of ShowRoomB (base of ShowRoomA) ... I have tried some thing like... but not sure.

    public class audiModelB:audi
    {
            public string JetEngine { get; set; }
    }
    public class benzModelB:benz
    {
            public string JetEngine { get; set; }
    }
    public class ShowRoomB
    {
            public audiModelB AudiModelB { get; set; }
            public benzModelB benzModelB { get; set; }
    } 

// My new code to Implementation class like this
    class Main()
    {
      private void UpdateDetails()
      {
        ShowRoomB ojbNahi = new ShowRoomB();
        GetDetails( ojbNahi ); // this is NOT working! I know this object does not contain base class directly, still some what i want fill my new model with old properties. Kindly suggest here 
      }
    }
```

Can any one please give me solutions how to achieve my extending requirement for base class "ShowroomA"

Really appreciated your time and suggestions.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Can you pick an answer if any helped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
  private void GetDetails(ShowRoomA objShowRoom)
  {
     objShowRoom = new objShowRoom();  //<-----
```

You're not using the object you passed in - instead you're creating a NEW object and using it.  just remove

```
objShowRoom = new objShowRoom();
```

and fix this block:

```
     objShowRoom.benz= new benz();
     objShowRoom.audi.Name = "BENZMODEL34LCX";   //<--- should be objShowRoom.benz?
     objShowRoom.audi.AC = "8 TON";
     objShowRoom.audi.AirBag = "Two (1+1)";
     objShowRoom.audi.MusicSystem = "Poineer 3500W";
```

and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks i just corrected. Its type mistake. Given example is sample which simulates my original one. To make clear understand i have taken car as an example. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would create a Car class for starters:

```
public class Car
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string AC { get; set; }
    public string PowerStearing { get; set; }
    public string MusicSystem { get; set; }
}
public class Audi : Car
{
}
public class Benz : Car
{
}
```

And a ShowRoom class, with a list of Car:

```
public class ShowRoomA
{
    public List<Car> Cars { get; set; }

    public virtual void GetDetails(ShowRoomA showRoom)
    {
        // Do your stuff
    }
}
```

Which you could extend as well:

```
public class ShowRoomB : ShowRoomA
{
    public override void GetDetails(ShowRoomA showRoom)
    {
        // Do some other stuff
    }
}
```

And use as such:

```
class Main()
{
    private void UpdateDetails()
    {
        ShowRoom ojbMahi = new ShowRoom();

        Audi audi = new Audi() { Name = "AUDIMODEL94CD698", AC = "6 TON" };
        objMahi.Cars.Add(audi);

        Benz benz = new Benz() { Name = "BENZMODEL34LCX", AC = "8 TON" };
        objMahi.Cars.Add(benz);
    } 
}
```

Comment: What ever given example is simulation of my original class which is more complex. I cannot change my class structure since already my model for ShowroomA in Production.

Comment: @user1888033 I would rethink your implementation based on the structure and classes you have at the moment, since they will become a problem in the future. However, you could just extend ShowRoomA with ShowRoomB and override the method GetDetails in ShowRoomB.

Comment: @user1888033 Updated answer to include new changes.

Comment: @user1888033 Updated the answer to include sample. You'll need to be more specific as to what are you trying to do, but can't at the moment, though.